# Angular 7 error in application can't read 'ceil' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I have an angular 7.0.2 project,

Everything works fine when angular build optimisation is false,

But when i build using the :

```
 "optimization": true
```

the build finishes with success, my app start without any error, then when i try to sign in with **Aws Amplify** i got the error :

> can't read 'ceil' of undefined

when i set

```
 "optimization": false
```

every things works fine.

**UPDATE**

It's a possible bug from amplify-angular
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in the terser plugin. it is now fixed in terser@3.10.10.

Angular CLI does not depend on terser directly, but you can force it to update by following these steps:

1. Check the current installed version of terser: npm ls terser
2. Install and uninstall terser to update your lockfile npm install terser@3.10.10 npm uninstall terser
3. New terser upldate is good

That worked for me.